# Generating one permutation of a string

Tags: java, python, algorithm, math, permutation

I'm reading this paper (page 3 and page 8): http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P05/P05-1077.pdf where it defines a permutation function to generate a permutation of a signature. The signature is a string of bits like "1001"

It defines the permutation function as the following: 
[image]

However when I apply it, it doesn't work. Suppose I have the string "1001", its indices are {0,1,2,3}. The aim is to have the indices permuted for example as {2,3,0,1}. Let p = 7, a =1 and b = 2. Now I need to permute the indices so:

pi(0) = (0+2) mod 7 = 2

pi(1) = (1+2) mod 7 = 3

pi(2) = (2+2) mod 7 = 4 <<<<<< here the problem starts as it generates a wrong value that's beyond the index space

pi(3) = (3+2) mod 7 = 5 <<<<<< same is here

So I end up with new indices as {2,3,4,5} which is invalid because I don't have 4 and 5 as indices in the first place.

What's wrong with my solution? Am I doing something wrong?

I've seen posts on stackoverflow that generate all the permutations of a string. But I want to generate one permutation using a specific permutation function. Because I want to use the same permutation function over multiple strings. Then I want to be able to create another permutation function using different parameters and apply the new one on the same set of strings/signatures.

Edit:
I found this piece of code in python that apply the same idea, but unfortunitly I never worked with python before, so I hope if someone can see what's different:

```
class Permutation(object):
    def __init__(self, maximumValue): 
        if not isPrime(maximumValue): raise Exception('Maximum value should be prime')
        self.p, self.a, self.b = maximumValue, random.choice(range(maximumValue)[3::2]), random.choice(range(maximumValue))
    def applyFunction(self, x): return (self.a*x+self.b)%self.p
    def __eq__(self, other): return self.a==other.a and self.b==other.b and self.p==other.p
    def __str__(self): return 'p: %s, a: %s, b: %s'%(self.p, self.a, self.b)
```

The code is from here: https://github.com/kykamath/streaming_lsh/blob/master/streaming_lsh/classes.py

Comment: Since you haven't shown us your code, it's going to be very hard for anybody to help.

Comment: @JimGarrison It's not about the code because the array is out of index because of the permutation function generating a wrong value. The problem is mainly with the permutation algorithm, which I showed how it calculates the new indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given function is essentially a random number generator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator. To get your permuted indices you need to mod the result by your array size. So for `1001` you would use `pi(x) % 4`.

edit : 
Thinking about this some more, this function is unlikely to be one-to-one since you will end up having things like `0 mod 4 = 4 mod 4` but `0 mod 7 != 4 mod 7`.

In order to generate elements within your range you must instead repeatedly apply the function until you get numbers in your range. So if you get `pi(0) = 6` try `pi(6)` instead, and if `pi(6) = 5` try `pi(5)`.

In the code that you posted the author seems to always use prime size arrays for permutation so he does not have this problem.

Comment: I added a code from the author of the paper but it's in python. I'm not very good in python but I don't see that it mod by the array size. Could you have a look please?

Comment: I tried what you said with a test text but some of the indices get excluded from the result. So if I have "gucko", I sometimes get "kogog"

Comment: You're right. See edit.

Comment: I don't see the python code doing any of that

Comment: Yeah he isn't doing that. If you look through all of the code in that library you will see that he is only using prime size data structures everywhere. I have not read that article except for the section where the function was mentioned, but that part seemed to say that in the procedure being described one has to first choose an arbitrary number of unit random vectors so it may just be convenient to choose a prime number of these vectors and use the simple formula straight up.

Comment: you mean to choose the signature length to be prime? I already tried with "gucko" (5) and as I told you it gives wrong results like "kogog"

Comment: Right, in that case you should pick `p` in your `pi` function to be 5, not any other prime and use the formula without any modifications / extra steps.

Answer (score 1):

What you needed, is a random permutation of a string. Rather than using the one, specified in the paper, you could use Knuth shuffle for this. Idea behind random permutation is that getting one should be of the probability 1 / n!. That is it. You could use any algorithm which satisfies this criteria. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation

Ok, your code is producing indices in the range of 0, P. But your source array is of length < P. So, it causes out of bounds. One way to solve this issue is pad the source array with pre decided padding chars to make the length, P. and in the result permutation, remove all the padding chars and shrink. Always make sure, P >= length of your source string.